# How to bind array data from Json to knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, data-binding

Please find below code from .cshtml page

Below code gives databind for observables but not for observable array.

```
var getLocationDetails = function (locationCode)
{
    return $.getJSON('@Url.Action("MasterDetails")', 
       { locationcode: locationCode });
};

var setModelData = function (self, locationDetails)
{
    self.UneditedLocationDetails = _(locationDetails).cloneDeep();
    for (var key in locationDetails)
    {
        locationDetails[key] = ko.observable(locationDetails[key]);
    }
    function LocationModifyViewModel()
    {
         var self = this;
         initAjax(self);
         var initModel = setModelData.bind(self);
         var initModel = setModelData.bind(self);
         self.TextboxLocationcode.subscribe(function (val)
         {
             getLocationDetails(val).success(function (locationDetails) {               
                setModelData(self, locationDetails);
             });
```

In the above code databinded to `locationDetails`, where I want to add observablearray values to locationDetails or else if possible to new variable.

Comment: Plase format your code.

Comment: Please respond for above query

Comment: It's not currently clear from your question what you're trying to do. Maybe try and illustrate it with a JSFiddle example?

Comment: Please, improve your question. You're showing partial code, and not explaining what code runs, what you expect to happen and what happens instead. Can you add the missing code and explian it?